# Expresión REGEX que seleccione paréntesis y contenido

Tags: regex

En una base de datos, tengo un campo que contiene `strings` compuestos de un número seguido de un paréntesis que contiene otro número (p.ej. `12(15)`). Necesito escribir una expresión RegEx que seleccione el paréntesis y todo lo que contiene (en el ejemplo anterior, necesito seleccionar `(15)`). Lo he intentado, sin éxito, con estas expresiones

```
\\((.*?)\\)
\\([^()]*\\)
```

¿Dónde está el error?

Comment: Tienes que escapar los paréntesis internos: `(\([0-9]*\))`.

Comment: Tienes razón. Si lo pones como respuesta, la valido. Muchas gracias.